# Скрипт, выполняющийся автоматически

Tags: linux

Добрый день, как сделать так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся автоматически каждые несколько часов (и/или при запуске системы)? Если можно пару ссылок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Unix/Linux системах периодическое выполнение задач осуществляется демоном [cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#crontab). Для добавления расписания в список задач вызывается редактор crontab и добавляется запись вида

```
# m  h dom mon dow user    command  0 */1 *   *   *  root    echo "Выполняется в 0:00, 1:00, 2:00 и тд."
```

Что бы поставить скрипт на выполнение после загрузки, в файл [`/etc/rc.local`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto) добавляется соответствующая команда:

```
echo "Выполняется после загрузки"
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно, только редактор вызывается командой

```
crontab [-u username] -e
```

Если не указать `[-u username]`, то будет редактироваться cron для текущего пользователя.

Ещё команды надо бы указывать полностью, т.е. вместо

```
echo
```

надо бы указать

```
/bin/echo
```

(unix не любит недоговорок)

Можно бы еще указать переменные HOME и PATH например так

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/binHOME=/home/username
```